# Copy and pasting in java textArea causing problems

Tags: java, textarea, whitespace

I am using a textArea to gather information from the user. The user must enter one piece of information per line. To record this information, I am using a string array. When I test it, it works if I type the lines by hand, but if i copy and paste information for the lines and delete the white space, I get a NumberFormatException.

```
//from applet class
private void record(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    Test.copy(display.getText());

}
```

class Test

```
public class Test{

    public Test() {

    }

    public void record() {    
        String [] lines = new String [4];

        lines = str.split("\n");

        String workerName = lines[0];
        String workerDepartment = lines[1];
        String workerID = lines[2];
        String workerPhone = lines[3];


        int wID = Integer.parseInt(workerID);
        int wPhone = Integer.parseInt(workerPhone);
    }
}
```

Example

This works...

> john
>
> boss
>
> 10
>
> 5555555555

This doesn't

paste

> john boss 10 5555555555

(click before boss, press enter, click before 10, press enter, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are splitting only on a newline. Try replacing this:

```
lines = str.split("\n");
```

with this:

```
lines = str.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: I'm getting the same results

Comment: Could you by chance post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? Also is there any reason you are not using a TextField (one for each input)?